# Paneer melts like Mozzarella cheese in my curry

Tags: paneer

When I make my paneer and store it, it is firm and I am able to cut it into cubes. But when I add it to a curry sauce at the end or when I try to shallow fry it, it melts like Moz. I make it with whole milk and curdle with vinegar. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: What is the amount of milk and vinegar used in the curdling process ? What is the acid concentration of the vinegar used ? Did you get clear separation of the paneer curds from the whey ? Did you press the water out of the paneer curds before allowing it to _set_ ? What type of curry sauce melts the paneer ?

Comment: Are you following the processes mentioned in this [Related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10363/62059)? [This comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14881/does-paneer-have-to-be-cooked/27858#comment37032_27858) and [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/100003/62059) hints / mentions the role of acid.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a firm paneer, it's good to steam the block for some time. After cooling you can cut it for your recipe. Also try frying at a high heat.

Comment: @Sam you can [edit](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/122483/edit) your posts to fix errors that you find later.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't heat your milk enough when making the paneer.

As part of making the cheese, you should [heat the milk](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-paneer-cheese-in-30-minutes-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-57008) to a temperature between 90C and boiling, before adding the acid.  This heating is what makes paneer resistant to melting as cheese.